# "Incorrect reference to the object" OR "Message: Outline childs load error."

Tags: php, pdf, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-pdf

The program is creating PDF attachments with and loading pdf files with Zend_Pdf . I know that  Zend_Pdf can only work with PDF files equal or lower than 1.4 version.

All files are of 1.3 version. Five pdf attachments are created and attached correctly, but one file is producing an error when loading. I am not sure what is the reason and how to fix it:

**Error 1: when files are downgraded to 1.3 version**

```
An error occurred

Application error

Exception information:

Message: Outline childs load error.

Stack trace:

#0 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Pdf\Outline\Loaded.php(345): Zend_Pdf_Outline_Loaded->__construct(Object(Zend_Pdf_Element_Reference), Object(SplObjectStorage))
#1 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Pdf\Outline\Loaded.php(345): Zend_Pdf_Outline_Loaded->__construct(Object(Zend_Pdf_Element_Reference), Object(SplObjectStorage))
#2 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Pdf\Outline\Loaded.php(345): Zend_Pdf_Outline_Loaded->__construct(Object(Zend_Pdf_Element_Reference), Object(SplObjectStorage))
#3 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Pdf\Outline\Loaded.php(345): Zend_Pdf_Outline_Loaded->__construct(Object(Zend_Pdf_Element_Reference), Object(SplObjectStorage))
#4 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Pdf\Outline\Loaded.php(345): Zend_Pdf_Outline_Loaded->__construct(Object(Zend_Pdf_Element_Reference), Object(SplObjectStorage))
#5 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Pdf\Outline\Loaded.php(345): Zend_Pdf_Outline_Loaded->__construct(Object(Zend_Pdf_Element_Reference), Object(SplObjectStorage))
#6 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Pdf\Outline\Loaded.php(345): Zend_Pdf_Outline_Loaded->__construct(Object(Zend_Pdf_Element_Reference), Object(SplObjectStorage))
#7 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Pdf\Outline\Loaded.php(345): Zend_Pdf_Outline_Loaded->__construct(Object(Zend_Pdf_Element_Reference), Object(SplObjectStorage))
#8 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Pdf.php(549): Zend_Pdf_Outline_Loaded->__construct(Object(Zend_Pdf_Element_Reference))
#9 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Pdf.php(317): Zend_Pdf->_loadOutlines(Object(Zend_Pdf_Element_Reference))
#10 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Pdf.php(253): Zend_Pdf->__construct('C:\WebSites\Web...', NULL, true)
#11 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\application\modules\default\models\Students.php(609): Zend_Pdf::load('C:\WebSites\Web...')
#12 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\application\modules\default\controllers\StudentsController.php(262): Model_Students->generateDocuments()
#13 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(513): StudentsController->quizCompletedAction()
#14 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(289): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('quizCompletedAc...')
#15 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#16 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#17 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#18 C:\WebSites\RSS\Workstudy\index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
```

**Error 2: it probably happens when files are not downgraded properly to the lower version **

```
An error occurred

Application error

Exception information:

Message: Incorrect reference to the object

Stack trace:

#0 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Pdf\Element\Reference.php(128): Zend_Pdf_Element_Reference->_dereference()
#1 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Pdf.php(529): Zend_Pdf_Element_Reference->getType()
#2 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Pdf.php(317): Zend_Pdf->_loadOutlines(Object(Zend_Pdf_Element_Reference))
#3 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Pdf.php(253): Zend_Pdf->__construct('C:\WebSites\Web...', NULL, true)
#4 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\application\modules\default\models\Students.php(597): Zend_Pdf::load('C:\WebSites\Web...')
#5 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\application\modules\default\controllers\StudentsController.php(262): Model_Students->generateDocuments()
#6 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(513): StudentsController->quizCompletedAction()
#7 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(289): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('quizCompletedAc...')
#8 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#9 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#10 C:\WebSites\Web_Applications\workstudy\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#11 C:\WebSites\RSS\Workstudy\index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
#12 {main}
```

**Php code:**

```
...

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setFrom(Zend_Registry::get('config')->app->contact->email);
$mail->addTo($this->getUscEmail(), $this->getFirstName().' '.$this->getLastName());
$mail->addCc(Zend_Registry::get('config')->app->contact->email, 'SOWK FWS');
$mail->setSubject('Workstudy Documentation - '.$this->getFirstName().' '.$this->getLastName());
$content = '......text......';

$mail->setBodyText(strip_tags($content));
$mail->setBodyHtml($content);


...

$file = Zend_Registry::get('config')->app->pdf_path."Foundation Year Students.pdf"; //load pdf from string
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load($file);
$at1 = $mail->createAttachment($pdf->render());
$at1->filename = "Foundation Year Students steve.pdf";
$at1->type        = 'application/pdf';

...
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way to attach the same file fixed the problem:

```
    $file = Zend_Registry::get('config')->app->pdf_path."Foundation Year Students-Instructions.pdf"; //load pdf from string
            $content = file_get_contents($file); // e.g. ("attachment/abc.pdf")
    $attachment = new Zend_Mime_Part($content);
    $attachment->type = 'application/pdf';
    $attachment->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
    $attachment->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
    $attachment->filename = 'Foundation Year Students-Instructions.pdf'; // name of file

    $mail->addAttachment($attachment);
```